# How can I include empty strings in HTML text() extracted with XPath?

Tags: parsing, xpath, scrapy

I have a page which consists of a table with two columns.

```
header  |  value
----------------
field1  |   1
field2  |
field3  |   1
field4  |
field5  |   1
```

When I select the values I need to get the same number as there are fields. I get the right number with:

```
>s = scrapy.Selector(response)
>values = s.xpath('//tr/td[@class="tdMainBottom"][2]').extract()  # get the second column
>len(values)
5
```

But:

```
>s = scrapy.Selector(response)
>values = s.xpath('//tr/td[@class="tdMainBottom"][2]/text()').extract()  # get the values
>len(values)
3
```

I can clean the first list up afterwards, but is there a one-shot way of doing this in XPath/Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

This works but is kind of ugly:

```
values = [v.xpath('text()').extract()
          for v in s.xpath('//tr/td[@class="tdMainBottom"][2]')]
```